# Vuepress custom theme and postcss

Tags: vue.js, vuepress

I made a custom vuepress theme and published it on npm. 
Then I import it in a vuepress project, and the theme shows up.

The problem: the postcss plugins required by the theme are not processed.

The postcss plugins are in the `dependencies` of the theme's package.json and in the theme's `index.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
    postcss: {
      plugins: [
        require('postcss-normalize'),
        require('postcss-preset-env')({
          stage: 0
        })
      ]
    }
  }
```

It does not work.

**What is the correct way to register the postcss plugins in the vuepress theme?**

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to [this issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vuepress/issues/2155), it looks like a bug